# C# & SQL Server 2008 : how to use code first?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, code-first

I was trying to implement in C# a code first project does any one has tried this?

Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

[Tutorial: Code First With EF 4.1](http://codefirst.codeplex.com/)